# Is it possible to install SQL Server 2000 on my PC?

Tags: database, sql-server-2000

I am pretty much new to using SQL Server 2000. I have been using only open source databases until this time. I want to know if there is any developer version of SQL Server 2000 available. It's for learning purposes only. Is it available free or do I need to pay for it?

Thanks

Comment: MSDE 2000 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=413744d1-a0bc-479f-bafa-e4b278eb9147&displaylang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download and install SQL Server express 2005. It's free of charge.

http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx

SQL Server express 2008 is here:
http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/
But I had problems installing it myself. I'm still using the 2005 version.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need 2000, the only way I know of is to subscribe to buy an MSDN subscription. It's still available on the subscribers download page (though I'd do it soon -- it's old enough it wouldn't surprise me if it disappeared soon).

Comment: Well, the MSDN downloads page still has SQL Server 6.5, 7, Windows 3.1, MSDOS 6.22 and Visual Basic 2 there. I'm not expecting SQL 2000 to disappear before any of those.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight:well, probably not before SQL Sever 6.5 and 7, that's true. DOS, Windows, VB, etc., will probably stay almost forever, because there's no *direct* replacement.

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

and google ;)

http://www.google.nl/search?hl=nl&client=firefox-a&hs=LJN&rls=org.mozilla%3Anl-NL%3Aofficial&q=expess+sql+server+2008&meta=&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Answer (score 0):

you can try the SQL_SERVER's express verison
  that's free！ download on the MS's website